# Airline binomial distribution overbooking question

Tags: probability-distributions

> An airline has a plane with 400 seats. The probability that a passenger fails to turn up for their flight is 0.04.
>
> The airline has an overbooking policy. Find the largest number of passengers this airline can book and still be at least 85% sure that everyone who shows up has a seat.

Working:

Need to find a value $x$ when $1 - \text{cumulative probability}$ is at least 0.85 or more, but as close to 0.85 as possible. If we call this $x$-value $Z$ we need:

$[1 – P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) +…+ P(X = Z)]   $

So $n=400 p=0.04 q=0.96 x=0,1,2,...$

Can't seem to add a picture of the answers but I got it as $411$.

Would anyone be able to verify that this method is correct ?

Comment: May be this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571558/binomial-distributionoverbooking-plane-tickets), or this one [link](http://nrich.maths.org/4932) with clue [link](http://nrich.maths.org/4932/clue) and solution [link](http://nrich.maths.org/4932/solution) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it helps noticing that when the number of trials is large and the probability is small within a binomial distribution you can approximate the distribution to the poisson distribution using

$$ X: Binomial(n,p) \rightarrow Y: Poisson(\lambda = np) $$

Comment: In which case would the method I used still be correct?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm unsure. I would say $X: Binomial(400,0.04) \rightarrow Y : Poisson(\lambda = 16)$ and as $P(Y \le 20) = 0.8681.. \gt 0.85$ we have that we can be 86% sure (more than 85% certain) that 20 passengers won't turn up. Allowing 420 passengers to be booked with 86% certainty that only 400 will turn up. Hopefully someone can verify your method though.